# Firebase IndexedDB transaction is not active

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, webpack, indexeddb

I am experiencing an issue with **Firebase** in a **React Native Web** application bundled with **Webpack**. The problem arises when I switch to **production** mode. In development mode, everything works perfectly fine, but when I build for production, I encounter the following error:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'put' on 'IDBObjectStore': The transaction is not active.

This error seems to be related to **IndexedDB** transactions.

**Firebase initialization code:**

```
import {initializeApp} from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '---',
    authDomain: '---',
    databaseURL: '---',
    projectId: '---',
    storageBucket: '---',
    messagingSenderId: '---',
    appId: '---',
    measurementId: '---',
};

firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebaseApp.automaticDataCollectionEnabled = true;
```

**Webpack config:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin = require('@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

const babelConfig = require(path.resolve(appDirectory, 'babel.config'));

// Babel loader configuration
const babelLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(tsx|jsx|ts|js)?$/,
    include: [
        path.resolve(appDirectory, '../libs'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, './src'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, './app.json'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, '../node_modules'),
    ],
    exclude: [
        path.resolve(
            appDirectory,
            '../node_modules/@firebase/app/node_modules/idb',
        ),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, '../node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, '../node_modules/babel-runtime'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, '../node_modules/glob'),
        path.resolve(appDirectory, '../node_modules/immer'),
    ],
    use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            cacheDirectory: true,
            // Presets and plugins imported from main babel.config.js in root dir
            presets: babelConfig.presets,
            plugins: ['react-native-web', ...(babelConfig.plugins || [])],
        },
    },
};

// Image loader configuration
const imageLoaderConfiguration = {
    test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
    use: {
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            esModule: false,
        },
    },
};

module.exports = (_, argv) => {
    return {
        target: 'web',
        devServer: {
            port: 8080,
            static: [{directory: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public')}],
            historyApiFallback: {
                index: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web'),
            },
        },
        entry: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src', 'main'),
        output: {
            clean: true,
            path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist'),
            filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
            sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].map',
            chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js',
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [
                '.web.js',
                '.js',
                '.web.ts',
                '.ts',
                '.web.jsx',
                '.jsx',
                '.web.tsx',
                '.tsx',
            ],
            alias: {
                'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
            },
        },
        module: {
            rules: [babelLoaderConfiguration, imageLoaderConfiguration],
        },
        plugins: [
            // Fast refresh plugin
            new ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin(),

            // Plugin that takes public/index.html and injects script tags with the built bundles
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public/index.html'),
            }),

            // Defines __DEV__ and process.env as not being null
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                __DEV__: argv.mode !== 'production' || true,
                process: {env: {}},
            }),

            new CopyWebpackPlugin({
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from:
                            path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public') +
                            '/**/!(*.html|*.ttf|*.woff|*.css|*.png|*.ico|*.svg)',
                        to() {
                            return path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist') + '/[name][ext]';
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        from:
                            path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public/fonts') +
                            '/**/(*.ttf|*.woff)',
                        to() {
                            return (
                                path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist/fonts') + '/[name][ext]'
                            );
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        from: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public/styles') + '/**/*.css',
                        to() {
                            return (
                                path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist/styles') + '/[name][ext]'
                            );
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        from:
                            path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/public/images') +
                            '/**/(*.png|*.ico|*.svg)',
                        to() {
                            return (
                                path.resolve(appDirectory, 'web/dist/images') + '/[name][ext]'
                            );
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        ],
        optimization: {
            // Split into vendor and main js files
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    commons: {
                        test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                        name: 'vendor',
                        chunks: 'initial',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    };
};
```

**Dev server command:**

```
webpack-dev-server --config {projectRoot}/web/webpack.config.js --mode development --history-api-fallback
```

**Production server command:**

```
webpack --config {projectRoot}/web/webpack.config.js --mode production
```

Could anyone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.